# Как сделать локатор, который будет ожидает пока страница загрузится

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста

страница: http://store.steampowered.com/tag/en/Action/#p=0&tab=Discounts

после перехода на вкладка `Specials` - надо подождать, пока страница загрузится, чтобы выбрать игру с максимальной скидкой

Локатор для всех скидок: `//div[contains(@id,'DiscountsTable')]//div[contains(@class,'discount_pct')]`

а как написать локатор, чтобы выбор игры проходил после того, как игра загрузилась ?